# Like/Dislike system like FB

Tags: php, mysql, vote

I have my tables set and the design I wanted...the only thing in my way of creating a sexy like/dislike system for my site is the actual PHP it would take (dont worry i wrote a bunmch of the code, its just not sending)

My problem is that my code isnt sending to any of the tables, so my question to you is how would I actually get it to send to the db?

Here's the code I have in place so far (along with the button)

Button

```
<form action="up.php">
<input type="image" value="upBtn" name="upBtn" id="upBtn" src="images/add.png"> Like
</form>
```

Actual code (up.php)

```
  <?php
    require 'connect2.php';

    if (isset($_POST['upBtn'])) {
               mysql_query("INSERT INTO votes (id, user, upvote, downvote) VALUES ('', '$username', '+ 1', '+ 0')");
               mysql_query("UPDATE searchengine SET rel = rel '+ 1' WHERE id = '$id'");
            }
    ?>
```

$user name def (on the top of the page all of this code is on)

```
if (isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
    $userid = $_SESSION['id'];
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
```

$id was already defined on the page since all of this is on the page I wanted the votes to appear

Comment: where are the values being used by the qeury getting set? ( $username and $id )? I do not see them being defined from a $_POST, $_GET, OR $_REQUEST

Comment: Show us more code. Problems with formatting? http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: All fields are blank in the DB after inserting, or are these blank rows even being inserted? If ID is auto-incremented, at the very least your fields should contain `1, '', 0, 0` respectively.

Comment: Then `$username` isn't being set. `echo 'username: $username';` before your insert query, refresh your page, and see what the output is. Also, instead of using `+1`, just do `1`, (same with `+0`) since your `upvote` and `downvote` will always be 0 upon insert. They are probably being evaluated as strings rather than arithmetic operations anyway.

Comment: if i inserted it as 1, would that add to upvote everytime someone votes?

Comment: Well, you're "inserting" a unique row into `votes`, so you only need to use `1`, and not `+1`, which seems to be evaluated as a string like I said above. Also, do you have `session_start()` defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `method="post"` to the form tag.  If it still doesn't work, you should put some debugging code inside the if statement to see if your queries are actually being run.

Comment: it actually sent! but all of the rows were blank:( any suggestions?

Comment: Is your ID field an auto incremented field? What are the default values for `upvote` and `downvote`? How is `$username` and `$id` defined?

Comment: upvote and downvote give users the power to vote on which article is the best. i just defined username and id is auto incremented

Comment: I mean in the DB, what are the default types/values of `upvote` and `downvote`? Such as integers, default to 0, or varchar, default to NULL? Can you show the code how you defined `$username` and `$id?`

Comment: oh they're just int defaulted to 0

Comment: i edited my question to show you how i defined username and id

Answer (score 1):

You should include the "id" as a hidden field in the form, as the id in the session may not be the id they are voting one, for instance, if they opened another post in a separate tab, and then voted on one that had been loaded before.  Also, are you sure the session variables are being saved correctly?  Depending on your PHP configuration, sessions are not started by default, in order to conserve resources, and you have to call [session_start()](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) at the top of each page to actually start the session.